# Is there some software in foss which can be used to do pick one name from number of names

Tags: linux, debian

A friend of mine is organizing a competition of sorts. He has asked to know if there is some software where one puts names of people who have answered correctly and then the software picks up a name and shares it as an answer. All names equally weighed and let the A.I. or whatever do its thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `shuf`:

```
$ cat /tmp/names
Bob
Nancy
Margaret
Sam

$ shuf -n1 /tmp/names
Margaret
```

The `-n1` says "output 1 line".